# Anylogic - Communicate between two agents

Tags: anylogic

I have a problem regarding Agent-based model.

I built two agents.
One has statechart.
I want that the statechart is able to be worked by other agents via send message or something..

How do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the AnyLogic Help topic named "Communication between agents". This will show you how to send messages back and forth between Agents. Then read the topic named "Message Triggered Transition". This will show you how to move between states using messages. Essentially, you make your state chart, change whatever transitions you need to Message Transitions so that they will respond to messages, and then you use `send(...)` to send messages to the Agent that has the relevant state chart. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The Anylogic Help and documentation has a guide on how to do it. http://www.anylogic.com/anylogic/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/agentbased/Communication.html